# What is the best spline to interpolate freq analiser graph

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, frequency-domain

the question is as it is in the topic: What is the best spline to interpolate freq analiser graph?

I am looking something simply and fast to implement. I read about catmull-rom it looks it could be good, but as I understand it needs 4 points to be defined. But I think in my case the best would be something that requires only 3 points defined (3 points for each freq bin). Is that possible at all?

Comment: I think you should include some example images of what you want.

Comment: for example like that: [Voxengo SPAN](http://www.voxengo.com/product/span/)